# Access Intune configuration settings in a React Native application?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, mdm, intune

My company is doing Mobile Device Management with Microsoft Intune. We've successfully deployed an internal iOS app (using the Apple Developer Enterprise Program).

With Intunes' configuration settings we're trying to make each user's individual email available to the mobile app.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/app-configuration-policies-use-ios

How do you normally access these types of settings in an app? I found this library but I'd need to eject from Expo which is not ideal for me:
https://github.com/robinpowered/react-native-mdm

Comment: Your only way is eject.

Comment: @evanss did you check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71107697/8079868

Comment: @MuhammadNuman, the best answer is yours, by my idea, the only rational way is ejecting. but your answer is good for situation that the developer don't want to eject. I mean creating custom config for expo. thanks. I upvoted that and hope you get the full bounty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add expo support into [react-native-mdm](https://github.com/robinpowered/react-native-mdm) by fork [react-native-mdm](https://github.com/robinpowered/react-native-mdm) and use [Config Plugins](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/)

here is the PR for adding expo support into the native package https://github.com/Shobbak/react-native-compressor/pull/62

After adding support you just have to do

#### Managed Expo

```
yarn install react-native-mdm_from_your_fork
```

Add the [react-native-mdm](https://github.com/robinpowered/react-native-mdm) plugin to your Expo config (`app.json`, `app.config.json` or `app.config.js`):

```json
{
  "name": "my app",
  "plugins": ["react-native-mdm"]
}
```

Finally, compile the mods:

```
expo prebuild
```

To apply the changes, build a new binary with EAS:

```
eas build
```

Answer (score 0):

As the MDM has native dependencies, You'll not be able to make it with Expo. Expo projects are written only in JavaScript and don't support packages that contain Objective-C or Java (Native code/dependencies).

Expo provides an advanced SDK called `ExpoKit` for when you absolutely need to use custom native code. However, there are some cases where developers need native capabilities outside of what Expo offers directly. The most common situation is when a project requires a specific Native Module (like MDM) that is not supported by `React Native Core` or the `Expo SDK`. You'll have to detach the Expo project to create Xcode and Android Studio projects that contain ExpoKit. This step will generate `android` and `ios` project directories. Then you would add custom Objective-C or Java the same way as with any other Xcode or Android Studio project.

The Expo docs warn about some of the downsides of writing custom native code and discourage most of our developers from taking this route, as Expo's motive, almost everything you need to do is better accomplished in a cross-platform way with JS. Writing in JS enables you to best take advantage of code aster deployment and benefit from ongoing updates and support from Expo. You should only do this if you have a particular demand from native code which Expo won’t do a good job supporting, such as (for example) specialized CPU-intensive video processing that must happen locally on the device, Custom native libraries.

Here are only two options to support the MDM, either eject the project or create `react-native-cli` project and migrate your project into newly created one.